# Lazy evaluation vs strict one applied to fib

Tags: functional-programming, lambda, ocaml

I have this OCaml problem:

1. Recall the polymorphic type `lazy` seen in class, the function `delay` which transforms a `thunk` into a `lazy_t` and the function `force` which evaluates a `lazy_t`. (Material seen in class)
2. Implement: (*Write a version by strict evaluation and then a version that uses lazy evaluation.*)

   - the creation of a list `fibo_list` of `50` elements which are the values of the Fibonacci
     sequence `fn` where `n` is selected at random (we restrict ourselves to small values, for
     example 0 ≤ n ≤ 40)
   - a function which from `fibo_list` takes a valid index of the list from the user and returns the associated value `fn`.

This is what I did, and is there anyway I can improve this solution?

```
  (* 1 *)

let rec fib n =
  if n < 2 then n 
  else fib (n-1) + fib (n-2);;

type 'a thunk = unit -> 'a;;

type 'a lazy_val =
  | Delayed of 'a thunk (* hold a future computation *)
  | Computed of 'a (* a value is stored *)
  | Exception of exn;;

type 'a lazy_t = 'a lazy_val ref;;

let delay f = ref (Delayed f);;

let force lzy = 
  match !lzy with
  | Computed f -> f
  | Exception e -> raise e;
  | Delayed f -> try let res = f () in lzy := Computed res; res 
                with e -> lzy := Exception e; raise e;;

(*let x = delay (fun () -> fib 40);;
Stdlib.Printf.printf "%d\n" (force x);; (* very long*)
Stdlib.Printf.printf "%d\n" ((force x) + (force x));; (* instantaneous *) *)

  (* 2: strict *)

let rec fibo_list acc_list n = 
  match n with 
  | 0 -> acc_list
  | _ -> fibo_list ((fib (Random.int 40))::acc_list) (n-1);;

let rec idx_val idx lst i =
  match lst with
  | [] -> failwith "index out of range"
  | h::t -> if (idx == i) then h else idx_val idx t (i+1);;

  (* 2: lazy *)

let rec fibo_list acc_list n = 
  match n with 
  | 0 -> acc_list
  | _ -> fibo_list ((delay (fun () -> (fib (Random.int 40))))::acc_list) (n-1);;

let rec idx_val idx lst i =
  match lst with
  | [] -> failwith "index out of range"
  | h::t -> if (idx == i) then force(h) else idx_val idx t (i+1);;
```

Comment: `==` in OCaml programs is usually a bug. It compares _physical_ equality rather than structural. The `;;` token is also unnecessary in an OCaml program.